# Change default font of controls in winforms

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008, formatting

Is there any way to change default font of controls in winforms.

I must change font in about hundred font in recent project and it's coming next project with other fonts and I wanna at start setting properly fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select all the controls that are part of the form with Ctrl + A.  Then change the font property.  Or you could write something that would do that for you in the code behind.

Comment: I think that is the only way :/